# Nginx fastcgi always include the request body with the response

Tags: php, docker, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

I have a strange problem with a nginx-fpm application ( one docker container with nginx and another one with a php fpm).

When i post (or put, patch) a request the body of the request is added in the response before the response (this issue appear 70 to 90% of my request, it's not always appearing):

the curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/foo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": "lorem ipsm"
}'
```

the response:

```
{
    "data": "lorem ipsm"
}<h1>foo</h1>
```

---

i have a simple nginx config:

default.conf

```
location ~ ^/foo\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_pass server:9000;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
location /foo {
 try_files $uri /foo.php;
}
```

fastcgi param

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

php file

```
<?php
echo '<h1>foo</h1>';
```

Nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

Php version: 7.2

Do you have an idea about this issue ?

Comment: I've been having the same issue.  When I do a POST request I see the POST params included in the response body.

If I restart the php-fpm container the problem goes away, but then eventually returns out of the blue.  The issue is definitely isolated to the php container. 

I'm running php:7.4-fpm-alpine

Comment: I found an open bug report. https://news-web.php.net/php.bugs/230493

Comment: I checked my container's php.ini today and noticed

 auto_prepend_file=php://input

After restarting the server, this setting returned to "no value"  which is what it should be.  There is something odd happening that is causing this setting to get set to php://input after some time.

I have gone ahead and explicitly set it to blank in my ini and will continue monitoring to see if the problem returns.

Comment: Found out that the auto_prepend_file setting actually keeps changing back and forth from none to php://input over and over as I refresh a page that outputs phpinfo();

Video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kofxya97gmydpi/Nov-22-2020%2014-17-58.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will focus `auto_prepend_file ` on my configuration.

Comment: Looks like the problem has not been resolved according to that bug report. Other people have reported the issue as well. I would recommend adding the mod_security module for nginx as well as setting up a default location on nginx which does not point to php at all. This way the attacker can only hit php via a domain name rather than default ip address, etc..

P.S. wodby/nginx has mod_security built-in

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this issue as well using nginx and php-fpm7.4.

I'm not sure what causes the issue, but I resolved the issue by passing: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file= \n allow_url_include=Off" ;` in the location section on the nginx .conf.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue on nginx:latest + php-fpm7.4

When I restart docker container, the problem goes away for a while.
However about 4~6 hours layer, auto_prepend_file option in PHP.ini, automatically changed to "php://input" and allow_url_fopen option changed to "On".

And a request which try to download and execute a file "http://194.38.20.199/p.sh" was detected by nginx log.
(I think this request is regards to this problem)

So, I block the request through IP (not domain) in my nginx config.
And then, the problem was solved temporarily.